# NodeJS check validity of SSL certification other host

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I want to check from my server, if the SSL certificate is valid on another server/domain. Is there any way how I can check this?

I think I need to use the [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) API from NodeJS, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you make an SSL request from NodeJS using its https library, it will take care of the job of verifying the validity of the server it's contacting.

From [NodeJS doc](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback):

> rejectUnauthorized: If true, the server certificate is verified
>   against the list of supplied CAs. An 'error' event is emitted if
>   verification fails. Verification happens at the connection level,
>   before the HTTP request is sent. **Default true**

Further more, you can assert the `res.socket.authorized` attribute in the response:

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  host: 'google.com',
  method: 'get',
  path: '/'
};

var req = https.request(options,
  function (res) {
    console.log('certificate authorized:' + res.socket.authorized);
  });

req.end();
```

You can also use `res.socket.getPeerCertificate()` to get detailed information on the server certificate.